# How to fix Chrome's high memory usage, even when closed?

Tags: google-chrome, memory

I'm on a Macbook Air with M1 chip running MacOS Monterrey 12.2.1.

I'm constantly running out of RAM, and finding that Chrome seems to be a huge RAM-hog - see screenshot. This is the case even AFTER I've closed Chrome. Anyone know why Chrome seems to be spinning off a bunch of renderer processes using 200MB each and a GPU helper which uses 800MB?

[image]

Comment: Chrome does that, one for each tab [most browsers do these days, Chrome is just the worst for it, in memory terms]. The global process is quite small, but the cumulative effect of many tabs is what you see here. They ought to all vanish once you quit Chrome. if not, reboot. I'd seriously suggest using Safari instead, it's far less of a memory hog.

Comment: i sincerely hope my answer was helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Running x86 (32 bit) chrome will limit this to 4GB

However on macOS... I used this command to do something with a VM a long time ago...

But, I dont remember exactly how it works.

reguardless you will have to make a script for the executable

- like: ulimit -v 4G __________

> ulimit -help

in whatever edit prog mac uses. (brew gives you nano)

Also Opera made a chrome based browser called "GX" which you can easily limit memory usage (and CPU)

but dunno if its on MACOS even though i have an imac on my desk.

let me know.

Comment: Mac CL pros feel free to edit this.